# Why is java 8 IntSupplier method named getAsInt() and not get()?

Tags: java, functional-interface

Is there any specific reason why it could not have been get() similar to Supplier interface?

Obviously same query applies for other interfaces (DoubleSupplier, BooleanSupplier, etc) too.

Comment: Because it returns the value as a primitive type. You cannot use primitives as the type `T` for a `Supplier<T>` and thus override the `T get()` method of `Supplier`. `IntSupplier` was made specifically to handle supplying an `int`, otherwise you could just user `Supplier<Integer>`.

Comment: The designers of the interface could have used get() if they wanted to.  I suspect they wanted to drive home  the fact that you are getting a primitive instead of an object.  It is a consistent naming convention and is also used for  LongSupplier and DoubleSupplier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `java.util.function.Supplier` is a generic class, it will always return an *object* matching the generic type specified. The `java.util.function.IntSupplier` class (also the `DoubleSupplier`, `BooleanSupplier`, etc. classes from the same package) returns a *primitive type*, not an object.

I believe the getter method is named `getAsInt` to clarify that what is returned is a primitive `int` rather than an `Integer` object.